# onClick в fragment

Tags: android, дерево, android-on-click

мне нужно в Fragment пункт меню дерева сделать кликабельным и чтобы при нажатии открывалось активити.

Код в Fragment

```
    private void fillFolder12(TreeNode folder12) 
{
        TreeNode currentNode56 = folder12;
        for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
            //dollars
            TreeNode file1 = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(R.string.ic_point, NAME + getResources().getString(R.string.dollars)));
            currentNode56.addChild(file1);
            //euros
            TreeNode file2 = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(R.string.ic_point, NAME + getResources().getString(R.string.euros)));
            currentNode56.addChild(file2);
            //roubles
            TreeNode file3 = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(R.string.ic_point, NAME + getResources().getString(R.string.roubles)));
            currentNode56.addChild(file3);
}
```

Допустим у меня есть пункт меню "Roubles" и мне нужно указать ему какое-то ID для того чтобы в public void onClick я мог его как-то указать? или как?
[image: Изображение из приложения]

Я пробовал так

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(TreeNode node, Object value)
    {
        Intent file = new Intent(getActivity(), KCustoms.class);
        startActivity(file);
    }
```

Но в этом случае при нажатии на любую часть будь то:"Money","Dollars","Euros","Roubles". Будет открывается активити KCustoms

Comment: `file1.setOnClickListener(v-> {/* тут код при нажатии*/});`?

Comment: 3 Ошибки 1.error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.7
(use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
2.error: not a statement
3.error: ';' expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно различать объекты TreeNode, и в зависимости от этого отличия запускать тот или иной Activity

```
@Override
public void onClick(TreeNode node, Object value)
 {  //извлекаем объект добавленный ранее через new TreeNode(...
    IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem nodeValue=node.getValue();

    //если объект не присвоен - выходим, ничего дальше не делаем
    if (nodeValue==null) return;

    //если текст объекта содержит символы записанные в R.string.dollars
    if (nodeValue.text.contains(getResources().getString(R.string.dollars))){
      //то запускаем KCustoms.class
      Intent file = new Intent(getActivity(), KCustoms.class);
      startActivity(file);
    }

    //если текст объекта содержит символы записанные в R.string.euros
    if (nodeValue.text.contains(getResources().getString(R.string.euros))){
       ...
    }
 }
```

Можно пополнить класс TreeNode новой переменной

```
public class TreeNode {
    private int mType=-1;
    ...

    //добавим новый конструктор
    public TreeNode(Object value, int nodeType) {
        children = new ArrayList<>();
        mValue = value;
        mType = nodeType;
    }

    //добавим новый метод получения типа
    public int getType() {
        return mType;
    }
}
```

И в коде сделать так:

```
private void fillFolder12(TreeNode folder12) 
{
        TreeNode currentNode56 = folder12;
        for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
            //dollars
            //обрати внимание последний параметр - 1
            TreeNode file1 = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(R.string.ic_point, NAME + getResources().getString(R.string.dollars)),1);
            currentNode56.addChild(file1);
            //euros
            //обрати внимание последний параметр - 2
            TreeNode file2 = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(R.string.ic_point, NAME + getResources().getString(R.string.euros)),2);
            currentNode56.addChild(file2);
            //roubles
            //обрати внимание последний параметр - 3
            TreeNode file3 = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(R.string.ic_point, NAME + getResources().getString(R.string.roubles)),3);
            currentNode56.addChild(file3);
}
```

```
@Override
public void onClick(TreeNode node, Object value)
 {  //извлекаем тип объекта
    int nodeType=node.getType();

    switch (nodeType){
      case 1:
        //запускаем KCustoms.class
        Intent file = new Intent(getActivity(), KCustoms.class);
        startActivity(file);
      break;
      case 2:
        //запускаем KASD.class
        Intent file = new Intent(getActivity(), KASD.class);
        startActivity(file);
      break;
      case 3:
        //запускаем FGH.class
        Intent file = new Intent(getActivity(), FGH.class);
        startActivity(file);
      break;
    }
 }
```